# Macbook Aluminium Late 2008 wont turn on

Tags: macbook

A couple of weeks ago I got out my old macbook aluminium and tried to turn it on, but nothing happened. I plugged it in and the red charging light was on so I just left it to charge in case for some weird reason that would affect it.

Aout an hour later I press the battery indicator button and it indicated the battery was full and the may safe was green.

I pressed the power button and still, like last time nothing happens. So I take it apart (don't worry, I have an idea what I'm doing) and nothing seems wrong inside apart from a bit of dust. So I literately give it a full autopsy and clean everything and put it back together. Everything stays the same. Still cant turn it on just like before I took it appart. I have tried taking out and reinserting the battery and restarting the PRAM and other various things and still no. The most function I can get out of it is charging the battery.

It was working fine the last time I used it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is not turning on at all, how were you able to reset the pram?

Comment: Isnt that done via taking out the battery and holding down the power for 5 seconds or something? Well whatever I have done I know one things for sure, I havent been able to get the fans going lets just put it that way haha.

Comment: Ok. I was not familiar with that option. I always do it by holding down [COMMAND] + [OPTION] + [P] + [R] before the grey screen appears (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379). So for a moment I thought you were at least able to boot.

Comment: Nope. Sadly not. Its sort of perplexing. It turned on fine the last time I used it. No idea whats wrong with it now. THe only sign of life it is showing is charging. The battery indicator works and thats about it function wise. So weird

Comment: How long did you wait for it to start? I've had a similar problem with my 2008 17" MB. I had it sitting in a drawer for years, tried to fire it up and nothing happened at all. Well, it turns out that it was simply deeply discharged. I had it hooked up to the charger, pressed the power button and well more than twenty hours later it suddenly decided to boot.

If I let it run down to 0% battery it still needs a few hours before it turns on again, even with the charger connected.

Answer (score -1):

Mine has the same issue. This has worked for me a couple of times now...
Shift+Control+Option keys at the left side of the keyboard and the Power button, and hold them all down. Release all four buttons at he same time and then press the power button to turn the Mac on.
19 May 2015, source
https://www.howtogeek.com/217158/what-to-do-when-your-mac-wont-start-up/

I held the keys down for a few seconds before releasing. The MacBook Pro also took maybe 7/8 seconds before I heard the cd drive which it always does before starting ( seeing if it is to boot from a cd I assume).